# how to avoid filesort on union all query

Tags: mysql

Please i have this query which uses filesort if combined(union all), but if executed separately works fine without file sort. Here i dont want to execute it separately but want to implement the union all option. Please someone should help.

```
(SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN *, 
                  topic_post_time, 
                  topic_title, 
                  topic_id                           AS tid, 
                  p.userid                           AS profile_id, 
                  Concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS poster_name, 
                  Concat(first_name, '.', last_name) AS profile_name, 
                  forum_id, 
                  topic_last_post_time, 
                  sch_name_abbrev, 
                  picture_small_url, 
                  profile_pix_upload_path, 
                  profile_pix_upload_path, 
                  LEFT(post_text, 100)               AS post_text 
 FROM   _forum_topics FORCE INDEX(topic_poster) 
    INNER JOIN _profile p 
            ON ( p.userid = _forum_topics.topic_poster ) 
    INNER JOIN _users 
            ON p.userid = _users.userid 
    INNER JOIN _class 
            ON _users.classid = _class.classid 
    INNER JOIN _unit 
            ON _class.unitid = _unit.unitid 
    INNER JOIN _department 
            ON _unit.deptid = _department.deptid 
    INNER JOIN _faculty 
            ON _department.facid = _faculty.facid 
    INNER JOIN _university 
            ON ( _faculty.schid = _university.schid ) 
 WHERE  _forum_topics.sub_forum_id IN( 133, 134, 135, 136, 
                                   137, 138 ) 
 ORDER  BY topic_last_post_time DESC 
 LIMIT  0, 20) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN *, 
                  topic_post_time, 
                  topic_title, 
                  topic_id                           AS tid, 
                  p.userid                           AS profile_id, 
                  Concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS poster_name, 
                  Concat(first_name, '.', last_name) AS profile_name, 
                  forum_id, 
                  topic_last_post_time, 
                  sch_name_abbrev, 
                  picture_small_url, 
                  profile_pix_upload_path, 
                  profile_pix_upload_path, 
                  LEFT(post_text, 100)               AS post_text 
 FROM   _sch_forum_topics s FORCE INDEX(topic_poster) 
    INNER JOIN _profile p 
            ON ( p.userid = s.topic_poster ) 
    INNER JOIN _users 
            ON p.userid = _users.userid 
    INNER JOIN _class 
            ON _users.classid = _class.classid 
    INNER JOIN _unit 
            ON _class.unitid = _unit.unitid 
    INNER JOIN _department 
            ON _unit.deptid = _department.deptid 
    INNER JOIN _faculty 
            ON _department.facid = _faculty.facid 
    INNER JOIN _university 
            ON _faculty.schid = _university.schid 
 ORDER  BY topic_last_post_time DESC 
 LIMIT  0, 20) 
LIMIT 
0, 20
```

Comment: am i correct, that the only difference in the queries is the `WHERE` condition?

Comment: is the filesort slowing down the execution times? because filesort normally doesn't slow down with an low number off records "Using temporary; Using filesort"  could be bad because it could result in the temporary MyISAM file that needs to be sorted with quicksort algoritm with random disk read I/O and random  write I/O  formula (assuming quicksort best case and 4 ms disk random access (10K disk)) ((20 log 20) * 0.004) ~ 0.1 second

Comment: But indeed filesort could be slow if the filesort algoritme has got an wrong estimate off records/rows from the MySQL optimizer.. STRAIGHT_JOIN could be an cause off this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the only difference is the WHERE clause. Just use an OR.

Also, ORDER BY is not accomplished in this context, not because MySQL is buggy, but because it does not have a logical meaning.

There is also an old MySQL bug which makes all UNIONs use temporary tables:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50674
and ordering a temporary table generated by a query means filesort

Answer (score 0):

@Federico

"There is also an old MySQL bug which makes all UNIONs use temporary tables: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50674 and ordering a temporary table generated by a query means filesort"

**I've made an anwser because an comment doenst allow code formatting**

C++ Source code off (file sql/sql_union.cc) MySQL 5.5.32  union looks like it always creates an temporary table..
See the code comments and function create_tmp_table

```
 /*
  Create a temporary table to store the result of select_union.

  SYNOPSIS
    select_union::create_result_table()
      thd                thread handle
      column_types       a list of items used to define columns of the
                         temporary table
      is_union_distinct  if set, the temporary table will eliminate
                         duplicates on insert
      options            create options

  DESCRIPTION
    Create a temporary table that is used to store the result of a UNION,
    derived table, or a materialized cursor.

  RETURN VALUE
    0                    The table has been created successfully.
    1                    create_tmp_table failed.
*/

bool
select_union::create_result_table(THD *thd_arg, List<Item> *column_types,
                                  bool is_union_distinct, ulonglong options,
                                  const char *alias)
{
  DBUG_ASSERT(table == 0);
  tmp_table_param.init();
  tmp_table_param.field_count= column_types->elements;

  if (! (table= create_tmp_table(thd_arg, &tmp_table_param, *column_types,
                                 (ORDER*) 0, is_union_distinct, 1,
                                 options, HA_POS_ERROR, alias)))
```